# My code dosen't produce errors but still gives no output

Tags: python, discord.py

So, I am fairly new to developing discord bots and I am stuck on a simple code.I use **PyCharm** with **Python 3.7** and **1.5.1 version of discord.py**. My following code for ping doesn't give any errors, but still i don't get the output i.e.the latency in my discord test server.

```
import aiohttp
import discord
import asyncio


from discord.ext import commands
token=''

bot=discord.Client()
bot=commands.Bot(command_prefix='~')
bot.remove_command('help')
activity = discord.Game(name="| ~help")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Login Sucessful')
    print(bot.user.name)
    print('Bot ID:',bot.user.id)
    await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=activity)

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'Ping:{round(bot.latency * 1000)}ms')

bot.run(token)
```

Comment: yes, i updated to include most of my code

Comment: Code works fine on my side

Comment: om my side, when i run the command '~ping' on my discord server. No output is given (on discord). :(
Btw Thanks for your help. I'll check my packages and console for problems now...

Comment: Have a look to see if your bot has the correct permissions on the server. Otherwise your installation may be faulty

Comment: Please delete the 9th line (`bot=discord.Client()`) its useless

Comment: I too think that there's a fault in the installation because the bot has administrator permissions

Comment: Ok I'll try deleting the 9th line.

Comment: I'm assuming this is working now. You do not need `pass_context=True` in the `@bot.command` decorator anymore because context (`ctx`) is always passed now.

Comment: Ok so I upgraded to Python 3.8.6 and reinstalled discord.py and it starts to work, btw thanks guys, I appreciate the help